# Animate Insertions to ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, animation

I'm finding WPF inscrutable at times. Given the following XAML how would one add triggers to animate (slide down, fade in) new items added to the ObservableCollection Timeline. I've seen various examples for list boxes but nothing for items control.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl Name="TimelineItem"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Timeline}"
                      Style="{StaticResource TimelineStyle}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TweetItemStyle}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Style="{StaticResource TweetImageColumnStyle}" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TweetImageStyle}">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ProfileImageUrl}" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                           Style="{StaticResource TweetNameStyle}"
                                           Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                           Style="{StaticResource TweetTimeStyle}"
                                           Text="{Binding TimeAgo}" />
                            </Grid>
                            <Controls:TextBlockMarkup Grid.Row="1"
                                                      Grid.Column="1"
                                                      Markup="{Binding MarkupText}"
                                                      Style="{StaticResource TweetStyle}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Separator Grid.Row="2"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TweetSeparatorTop}" />
                        <Separator Grid.Row="3"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TweetSeparatorBottom}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: A good article to refer: https://asimplify.com/wpf-itemscontrol-animation-insert-asimplify/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's been a while since I've animated WPF, but this should work by setting a `DataTrigger` in the `DataTemplate` of the `ItemsControl` for the Loaded Event.

A couple of notes:

1. Add the following xaml to the DataTemplate of the ItemsControl
2. Name the `<Grid>` inside the DataTemplate: "MyGrid"
3. Add a RenderTransformOriginproperty to the MyGrid to set the Y origin at the top:

   - `<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0">`
4. Be sure to include the `Grid.RenderTransform` attached property to your grid (see sample below)

**Xaml**

```
<DataTemplate.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ItemAnimation" AutoReverse="False">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</DataTemplate.Resources>

<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ItemAnimation}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

**Add the RenderTransform groups to your Grid**

```
<!-- Include in the Grid -->
<Grid.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform/>
    </TransformGroup>
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

This should get you close enough so that you can customize it yourself. FWIW: I used Blend to build out the animation by editing the style of the `ItemTemplate` of the `Timeline` object.

One last note: The animation will occur when the window loads the ItemsControl for the first time, for each item in the original collection. And will occur for an individual item when it is added to the collection. This behavior is a bit wonky, so you could remove the explicit binding of the trigger in the xaml and bind the trigger in the code-behind after the ItemsControl or Window loads.

**EDIT**

1. I've updated the example so that it should work with your XAML now.
2. Added another animation to slide (sort of) the new item. Actually, it's growing from a size of 0% to 100%, starting from the top of the Y axis.
3. Revised note #3 from above to include a `RenderTransformOrigin` property.
4. Added note #4 to include the `Grid.RenderTransform` attached property.

Comment: Excellent answer. The opacity works great but I'm getting an error with the slidedown. '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[3].(2)'. I've tried different children indexes but I'm not quite sure how to interpret the error

Comment: It appears I'm going to need a transform group to make the height animation work. I sort of got it to work by adding

    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <TranslateTransform Y="0" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>

Thoughts?

Comment: I've updated the example to fix the error you were receiving. I was using a bit different xaml than what you posted due to all the static resources and the custom control. I've included a few more notes at the bottom of the answer. HTH's.

Comment: Unfortunately the affect is not quite what I was hoping for. The contents "grow" but the space (height of the insert item) is already set to the full height. The contents grow into the allocated height. What I was really hoping for was the the height would change. I tried animating the height but the layout gets all screwed up. In CSS I could just animate the height. Doesn't seem possible in WPF.

Comment: I've come up with something that gets close to the effect I'm looking for. Instead of animating the items, I animate the entire items control using a transform animation of the Y offset. It slides down the whole list.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting effect. If I understand correctly, the height of the ItemsControl is pre-set. And you are wanting the newest item to "grow" at the bottom of the list which would essentially push the entire list up?

Comment: Not quite. I want it to grow from the top. The code you wrote works well but the affect is that a blank space immediately appears at the top of the list and then the contents scroll down and fade in. I want the "list" to grow down in an animated fashion with the contents fading in at the same time. I'm looking for the equivalent of the jQuery slideDown effect if that helps. As I imagine it, the height of the new item starts at 0 and grows to the actual height. I really appreciate your efforts here.

Comment: @MikeWard I know this question is very old, but do you remember what you used to animate the item height?

Comment: @SapuSeven I never did get the height thing to work. I just slid the whole list down and used a fade-in. Not what I wanted but it was as close as I could get.

Comment: If you know the height, you can animate the Height property, if not you can animate MaxHeight:
`<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.MaxHeight)">
   <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
   <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="750" />
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>`