# WPF Animate Insertion into an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

Earlier I asked about a fade-in,scroll down animation for items control insertion ( [Animate Insertions to ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654417/animate-insertions-to-itemscontrol) ). I got the fade-in working but I'm still perplexed about the items control insertion animation. Below is somethings that "sort of" works.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl Name="TimelineItems"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Timeline}"
                      Style="{StaticResource TimelineStyle}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TweetItemStyle}">
            <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <TranslateTransform />
                </TransformGroup>
            </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
            <ItemsControl.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.SizeChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TimelineItems"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                      Value="-50" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                      Value="0" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ItemsControl.Triggers>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Name="MyGrid"
                          Background="{Binding TweetType, Converter={StaticResource tweetTypeConverter}}"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Style="{StaticResource TweetImageColumnStyle}" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TweetImageStyle}">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ProfileImageUrl}" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                           Style="{StaticResource TweetNameStyle}"
                                           Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                           Style="{StaticResource TweetTimeStyle}"
                                           Text="{Binding TimeAgo}" />
                            </Grid>
                            <Controls:TextBlockMarkup Grid.Row="1"
                                                      Grid.Column="1"
                                                      Markup="{Binding MarkupText}"
                                                      Style="{StaticResource TweetStyle}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Separator Grid.Row="2"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TweetSeparatorTop}" />
                        <Separator Grid.Row="3"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                   Style="{StaticResource TweetSeparatorBottom}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="ItemAnimation"
                                    AutoReverse="False">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="MyGrid"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                      Value="0" />
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8"
                                                      Value="1" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>

                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ItemAnimation}" />
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I say "sort of" because the list is offset by a negative offset and then animated into position. The "animation to position" looks great, but the "jump" to a negative offset spoils the affect.

In CSS, I would simply animate the height of the inserted item but I haven't puzzled out how to do this in WPF.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I don't know all details, but I think usual way (I'm noob, lol) are:

1. Add FluidMove behavior to your visual collection
2. Insert new object with lower width and height, e.g. 1x1
3. Animate it to actual size via storyboard or manually DoubleAnimation

Comment: Sounds promising. I'm not familiar with the fluidmove behavior. Is this a blend behavior?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723946(v=Expression.40).aspx  

It comes with blend, if my mind don't lie, you need System.Windows.Interactivity and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.

Comment: Why I recommend to use FluidMoveBehavior? Because you can make fluid all your collection and animation will be smoother. Also you can set up animation type for all collection and use any types of math algorithms.

Comment: I've added the blend behavior but I'm at a loss as to how to use it.

Comment: Add it to collection container, set AppliesTo to Children and set easing functions. Must work.

Comment: I tried that but again, it just doesn't get me quite what I want. Also, it slows down scrolling with the scroll bars. I'm going to mark your response as the answer. I suspect with a bit of fiddling I'll get the right effect with fluid motion. It certainly seems like the right track. Thanks.