# How to create animation effects for ListBox control on WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation

I want to show some animation effects when I initialize a `ListBox` or add an item to it, how can I do that? I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you have some code share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FluidMoveBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723946%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).

Check out the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978307/reference-to-grid-in-child-usercontrol-from-window/18978799#18978799). (The example is on `ItemsControl` but it is exactly the same for `ListBox`)