# WPF animate ListViewItem appearence only once

Tags: wpf, listview, animation

I have a ListView which i want to animate its items when they are being added to the listview, i found a way to do it by doing this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" From="0,5" To="0,0" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                    </ Storyboard>
..........
```

The problem is that this animation triggers everytime the ListViewItem comes into view or simply reloaded, I want it to happen only one time (when the ListViewItem is added) and thats it.

How can i make the animation trigger only one time?

Comment: Try [FluidMoveBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724012(v=expression.40).aspx) instead

Comment: I don't have the required namespaces

Comment: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978307/reference-to-grid-in-child-usercontrol-from-window/18978799#18978799). It is demonstrated on `ItemsControl` but it can be used exactly the same with `ListView`.

Comment: Toda but i don't have the expression bled 2010 installed on my computer..

Comment: You download the dll's from [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801)

Comment: I can't connect my computer to the internet >< is there any way of doing this without fluid move?